# iterate a directory and find only file whose names start with the certain string

Tags: python

I have a directory path and in this path there are several folders. So i am  am trying to build a script which would find all the xml files and the file name must start with report. I have been so far able to iterate over all the directories but further i do not know how to proceed. Here is my code:

```
def search_xml_report(rootdir):
     for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            print os.path.join(subdir,file) # print statement just for testing
```

Comment: Maybe add `if file.startswith('report'):`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you

Comment: Just like you already did with `print`: `f(os.path.join(subdir, file))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `str.startswith` with `os.path.splitext`

`os.path.splitext`:  Split the extension from a pathname. Extension is everything from the last dot to the end, ignoring leading dots. Returns "(root, ext)"; ext may be empty.

```
 if file.startswith('report') and os.path.splitext(filepath+filename)[-1] == '.xml':
     return file
```

Comment: would like to know one for thing, suppose if i have the match and i would want to send the path of the file to a function then how do i do it?

Comment: I have implemented as in my question but with this additional lines:if file.startswith(str_file_startswith) and file.endswith('.xml'): function(file). Here file is just the file name but not the whole path

Comment: def foo(filepath): # do something, def getfile(): # do process; foo(filepath)

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.startswith`:

```
def search_xml_report(rootdir):
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith('report'):
                yield subdir, file
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But If i want only xml files with starting string "report" then?

Comment: @vinaycool You could also check that `file.endswith('.xml')`.

Comment: Or `os.path.splitext("blah.xml")[-1] == ".xml"` ... of course ending in `.xml` does not mean a file is xml